# restrict access to certain fields of model

Tags: flask, mongoengine, flask-restful

I have a mongoengine model which has some public fields and some fields that I want to hide from, for example, 'user' group. So, what is the smart way to restrict access to some fields?

My stack is Flask-Restful + mongoengine

My idea is to write custom resource serializer and a decorator which should do a restriction. However, the point which is not clear - should this decorator drop some fields from function output or, in opposite, add some fields that suits role?

```py
    @staticmethod
    def serialize_operator(event):
        json_to_decode = {
            "id" : str(event.id), 
            "title" : event.title,
            "description" : event.description,

            "type" : event.type # so I want to hide this field
        }
        return json.loads(json.dumps(json_to_decode))
```

```py
   @get_auth
   @some_restriction_decorator(user = get_auth())
   def get(self):
       pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest defining your serializer in your model class and use fields (from flask_restful) to define it. Then in your controller, you can use the [marshal_with](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/fields.html) decorator (or the marshal function) to serialize the return.

```
# Model definition
from mongoengine import Document, StringField
from flask_restful import fields

class Article(Document):
    title = StringField()
    description = StringField()
    type = StringField()

    public_serializer = {
        'id': fields.String,
        'title': fields.String,
        'description': fields.String
    }

# Controller
from flask_restful import marshal_with

...
@marshal_with(Article.public_serializer)
def get(self):
    return Article.objects.get(...)
```

This way only the fields specified in the serializer will be returned.

Note1: you can define the serializer wherever you want, I just like it to have it in the model.

Note2: marshal_with handle also list automatically, therefore `return list(Article.objects)` will also work

Note3: you can create several serializers and use them differently depending on the situation